# MYSQL QUERY FOR THE FOLLOWING SCENARIO

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have one table containing all users information.

**Example of the users table**

```
id      username           last_login        

1       david           2014-01-30 12:21:54

2       sam             2014-01-30 17:43:12

3       lynda           2014-01-30 10:31:31

4       mark            2014-01-30 21:21:15

5       john            2014-01-30 23:01:01

6       jakson          2014-01-30 16:21:31

7       mandela         2014-01-30 16:35:54

8       Ashy            2014-01-30 16:11:53
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

I want to select users by following criteria

- Some users (i.e user id 1,3,4,5,6) will be selected  based on `ORDER BY last_login ASC` and rest will be based on `ORDER BY id ASC` using a single query.

Is it possible or not ?

Thanks

Sanjog

Comment: if you can show me the result pls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can have multiple arguments to `order by`.  So, first identify the users you want ordered one way, then order them as you want, and order the rest:

```
order by userid in (1, 3, 4, 5, 6) desc,
         (case when userid in (1, 3, 4, 5, 6) then last_login end) ASC,
         id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your query also optimized

Answer (score 1):

One of possibilities would be to create 2 queries and join them using `UNION` for example

```
SELECT
Id,
UserName,
Last_login
from
Users
where Id 
in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
order by Id

UNION

SELECT
Id,
UserName,
last_login
from
Users
ORDER BY last_login ASC
```

Comment: This will not work.  `union` does not guarantee the order of the results in any database.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this mysql query:

```
select * from table_name where
id in (1,3,4,5,6) order by last_login
union 
select * from table_name where
id not in (1,3,4,5,6) order by id
```

Comment: This works but not optimized. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @SanjogKumarDash . . . This should not work.  No database guarantees the ordering of the result of a `union`, including MySQL.